# R: counting timestamps per week

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing a lot of tweets. Each tweet has a unique timestamp. Now, what I would like to calculate is how many tweets have been published in each week, based on the timestamp. Any ideas? I tried to do it with tidyverse and dplyr, sadly it didn't work.

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
tweets <- tibble(timestamp = sort(Sys.time() - runif(1000, 0, 365*86400)), tweet = paste("tweet", 1:1000))
tweets
# # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#    timestamp           tweet   
#    <dttm>              <chr>   
#  1 2021-01-27 09:39:47 tweet 1 
#  2 2021-01-28 02:38:29 tweet 2 
#  3 2021-01-28 07:33:02 tweet 3 
#  4 2021-01-29 08:42:47 tweet 4 
#  5 2021-01-29 09:21:58 tweet 5 
#  6 2021-01-29 16:01:09 tweet 6 
#  7 2021-01-30 05:04:18 tweet 7 
#  8 2021-01-30 21:45:05 tweet 8 
#  9 2021-01-31 18:32:24 tweet 9 
# 10 2021-02-02 02:57:51 tweet 10
# # ... with 990 more rows

tweets %>%
  group_by(yearweek = format(timestamp, format = "%Y-%U")) %>%
  summarize(date = min(as.Date(timestamp)), ntweets = n(), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 54 x 3
#    yearweek date       ntweets
#    <chr>    <date>       <int>
#  1 2021-04  2021-01-27       8
#  2 2021-05  2021-01-31      15
#  3 2021-06  2021-02-07      19
#  4 2021-07  2021-02-14      24
#  5 2021-08  2021-02-21      28
#  6 2021-09  2021-02-28      22
#  7 2021-10  2021-03-07      16
#  8 2021-11  2021-03-15      13
#  9 2021-12  2021-03-21      15
# 10 2021-13  2021-03-28      19
# # ... with 44 more rows
```

See [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for definitions of the various "week of the year" options (`"%U"`, `"%V"`, `"%W"`).